# Accessing My defined tags in RSS in C#

Tags: c#, .net, rss

I was able to add my own tag to a RSS feed (from reading the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644315/can-i-add-my-own-tags-in-a-rss-item)) but now I can't seem to be able to access the tag in code.

I tried modifying an already existing example feed ([this one](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/examples/rss2sample.xml)) adding just one tag,  as shown below.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:my="http://tempuri.org">
   <channel>
      <title>Liftoff News</title>
      <link>http://liftoff.msfc.nasa.gov/</link>
      <description>Liftoff to Space Exploration.</description>      
      <item>
         <title>Star City</title>
         <link>http://liftoff.msfc.nasa.gov/news/2003/news-starcity.asp</link>
         <description>How do Americans get ready to work with Russians aboard the International Space Station? They take a crash course in culture, language and protocol at Russia's &lt;a href="http://howe.iki.rssi.ru/GCTC/gctc_e.htm"&gt;Star City&lt;/a&gt;.</description>
         <pubDate>Tue, 03 Jun 2003 09:39:21 GMT</pubDate>
         <guid>http://liftoff.msfc.nasa.gov/2003/06/03.html#item573</guid>
         <my:br_id>1507</my:br_id>
      </item>          
   </channel>
</rss>
```

In code I have this class:

```cs
public class SimpleSyndicationItem
{
    public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Uri Link { get; set; }
    public string Id{ get; set; }

    public SimpleSyndicationItem(DateTimeOffset date, string title, Uri link, string id)
    {
        Date = date;
        Title = title;
        Link = link;
        Id = id;
    }
}
```

Where the Id property should receive the value in my:br_id, now, in the reading process I have this:

```cs
var RssItems = new ObservableCollection<SimpleSyndicationItem>();
var reader = XmlReader.Create("rssexample.xml");    
var feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);

foreach(var item in feed.Items)
{
  //This is the part where I want to access the tag's value, notice the ??
  RssItems.Add(new SimpleSyndicationItem(item.PublishDate, item.Title.text,
                                         item.Links[0].Uri, item.??));
}
```

At least intellisense is not showing br_id so I'm wondering what's the right way to access this tag in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `item.ElementExtensions[0]`?

Comment: thanks, item.ElementExtensions[0].GetObject<string>() did bring the correct value :D